# Compensation for delayed/cancelled flight still pending

Tags: compensation

The timeline/facts:

- On the 30th of June 2022 I was scheduled to fly with Wizz air from LTN to LCA. This concerned flight W64459 was delayed over 5 hours and then postponed. Therefore, I had requested a refund for the total amount of £ 350 through the website form.
- On the 30th of July 2022, I received a confirmation by email that I would receive my compensation from 14 to 20 workdays.
- More than 20 working days later and more specifically on the 29th of August 2022, I received an email from a Wizzair team member that the amount of 400 euros was sent to my bank account and that the money would be at my disposal from 20 to 30 workdays.
- I had then responded to them reminding them about the law:

  Passenger rights flight cancellation
  According to European Regulation 261/2004, in the event of a flight cancellation, I am entitled to a refund. You are obliged to refund the ticket price within 7 days after the delay/cancellation of the flight.

and the fact that I should get compensated in pounds instead of euros.

- I have never heard back from them and I can see that other people on Twitter are still waiting for their refund even months later.
- I have sent a form on https://www.aviationadr.org.uk/initial-complaints-check-page/ and I am still waiting without any updates.

My questions are:

a) Is there a way to push things so that I get my compensation without using a no-win-no-fee agency?
b) If Wizzair goes bust, will I get the refund. I have already sent the request so I assume, yes.